# Adding a List<Point> to a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, list, silverlight, collections, point

I have a Convert method which takes in `object value`. The value is populated with an array as such:

[image: points in <code>value</code>]

But then when I try and store `value as List<Point>` in a variable called `point`, `point` stays `null`:

```
public class PointsToPointsCollectionsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var points = value as List<Point>;

        if (points != null)
        {
            var pc = new PointCollection();
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                pc.Add(point);
            }

            return pc;
        }

        else return null;
    }
}
```

How can I assign `value as <List>` to the variable `var points`?

Thanks

Comment: U need to do this : `List<point> lst=new list<point>` , then `Point points` and finally add it to the list `lst.add(points);`

Comment: Post code that shows us how you “populated with an array”. Do not post screen shots of your IDE.

Comment: before u get downvotes, u still have a chance to make a good edit :)

Comment: You could cast to `IList<Point>` since `PointCollection` implements that interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look more closely at your screenshot you will see that the `value` variable is not an array of points but rather a `System.Windows.Media.PointCollection`. If you were to look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `PointCollection` class you would see that it does not implement `List<Point>` and so your attempt to perform a type conversion to a `List<Point>` is evaluating as `null` as expected.

You should change your type conversion to a type that `PointCollection` actually implements. Seeing as all you are doing is iterating over the collection to copy it, `IEnumerable<Point>` would be the most appropriate choice:

```
var points = value as IEnumerable<Point>;
```